# React native - optimization on Flatlist

Tags: react-native, jsx, react-native-flatlist

In my react native app, I created a screen that shows the user emojis organized by category. The emoji list contains about 800 emojis.

Code below:

```
import { 
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    FlatList,
    SafeAreaView
} from 'react-native';
import emojis from './emojis.json';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  
  const [isLoadingEmojis, setIsLoadingEmojis] = useState(true);

  const renderCategoryEmoji = (categoryEmoji) => {
    return (
      <View key={categoryEmoji.categoryId} style={{marginBottom: 10}}>
          <Text style={styles.categoryLabel}>{categoryEmoji.categoryName}</Text>
          <FlatList
              data={categoryEmoji.emojis}
              renderItem={renderEmojiItem}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
              numColumns={7}
              contentContainerStyle={{paddingBottom: 100}}
              onLayout={() => setIsLoadingEmojis(false)}
          />
      </View>
    );
  }    

  const renderEmojiItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ width: 47, height: 47, margin: 1}}>
          <Text style={{color: 'black', fontSize: 25}}>
            {item.emoji}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList style={{margin: 15, marginBottom: 50}}
        data={emojis}
        renderItem={({ item }) => renderCategoryEmoji(item)}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.categoryId.toString()}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );


}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 0,
    marginTop: 30,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  categoryLabel: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginVertical: 10,
    },
});
```

There are two problems that I am not able to resolve: The first is that the emojis take a long time to render on the device. The second is that, after finishing rendering, the actions on the screen are very slow, clicking on each emoji takes a long time to be triggered.

I would like some tips from you on how I can optimize and solve these two problems of mine

Thank you very much

expo demo: https://snack.expo.dev/@arogerio.net/optimized-rendering-in-flatlist?platform=web

Answer (score 1):

source: https://github.com/filipemerker/flatlist-performance-tips

### Props

One way to improve your `FlatList` is by tweaking it's props. Here are a list of props that can help your with that.

#### removeClippedSubviews

You can set the `removeClippedSubviews` prop to true, which unmount components that are off of the window.

[Default: `false`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13316#issuecomment-298044067)

**Win:** This is very memory friendly, as you will always have a little amount of rendered items instead of the whole list.

**Trade offs:** Be aware that this implementation can have bugs, such as missing content (mainly observed on iOS) if you use it on a component that will not unmount (such as a root navigation scene).
It also can be less performant, having choppy scroll animations for big lists with complex items on not-so-good devices, as it makes crazy amounts of calculations per scroll.

#### maxToRenderPerBatch

You can set the `maxToRenderPerBatch={number}`, which is a `VirtualizedList` prop that can be passed directly to `FlatList`. With this, you can control the amount of items rendered per batch, which is the next chunk of items rendered on every scroll.

[Default: `10`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/7d741d1119532213e2c30707320351fb56c63953/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L439)

**Win:** Setting a bigger number means less visual blank areas when scrolling (a better the fill rate).

**Trade offs:** More items per batch means less javascript performance, which means less responsiveness (clicking a item and opening the detail). If you have a static and non-interactive list, this could be the way to go.

#### updateCellsBatchingPeriod

While `maxToRenderPerBatch` tells the amount of items rendered per batch, setting `updateCellsBatchingPeriod={number}` tells to your VirtualizedList the delay, [in milliseconds](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/d01ab66b47a173a62eef6261e2415f0619fefcbb/Libraries/Interaction/Batchinator.js#L24), between batch renders. In other words, it defines how frequently your component will be rendering the windowed items.

[Default: `50`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/7d741d1119532213e2c30707320351fb56c63953/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L442)

**Win:** Combining this prop with `maxToRenderPerBatch` gives you the power to, for example, render more items in a less frequent batch, or less items in a more frequent batch. Which works the best for your use case.

**Trade offs:** Less frequent batches may cause blank areas. More frequent batches may cause responsiveness and performance loss.

#### initialNumToRender

You can set the `initialNumToRender={number}`. This means the initial amount of items to render.

[Default: `10`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/7d741d1119532213e2c30707320351fb56c63953/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L428)

**Win:** You can set this value to the precise number of items that would cover the screen for every device. This can be a big performance boost when rendering the list component.

**Trade offs:** You are most likely to see blank areas when setting a low `initialNumToRender`.

#### windowSize

You can set the `windowSize={number}`. The number passed here is a measurement unit where 1 is equivalent to your viewport height. The default value is 21, being 10 viewports above, 10 below, and one in between.

[Default: `21`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist.html#windowsize)

**Win:** If you're worried mainly about performance, you can set a bigger `windowSize` so your list will run smoothly and with less blank space. If you're mainly worried about memory consumption, you can set a lower `windowSize` so your rendered list will be smaller.

**Trade offs:** For a bigger `windowSize`, you will have a bigger memory consumption. For a lower `windowSize`, you will have lower performance and bigger chance of seeing blank areas.

#### legacyImplementation

[This prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#legacyimplementation), when true, make your `FlatList` rely on the older `ListView`, instead of `VirtualizedList`.

[Default: `false`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#legacyimplementation)

**Win:** This will make your list definitely perform better, as it removes virtualization and render all your items at once.

**Trade offs:** Your memory consumption goes to the roof and chances are good that a big list (100+) with complex items will crash your app.
It also fires a warning that the above tweaks will not work, because you're now on a ListView.

#### disableVirtualization

You will see people advocation the use of this prop on some issues. But [this is deprecated now](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist.html#disablevirtualization). This used to do something similar to `legacyImplementation`.

### List items

There are also some win-win strategies that involves your list item components. They are being managed by VirtualizedList a lot, so they need to be fast.

#### Use simple components

The more complex your components are, the slower they will render. Try to avoid a lot of logic and nesting in your list items. If you are reusing this list item component a lot in your app, create a duplicate just for your big lists and make them with less logic as possible and less nested as possible.

#### Use light components

The heavier your components are, the slower they render. Avoid heavy images (use a cropped version for list items, as small as possible). Talk to your design team, use as little effects and interactions and information as possible in your list. Save them to your item's detail.

#### Use shouldComponentUpdate

Implement update verification to your components. React's PureComponent implement a `shouldComponentUpdate` with shallow compasion. This is expensive here, because it need to check all your props. If you want a good bit-level performance, create the strictest rules for your list item components, checking only props that could potentially change. If your list is simple enough, you could even use

```js
    shouldComponentUpdate() {
      return false
    }
```

#### Use cached optimized images

I personally use [react-native-fast-image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) from [@DylanVann](https://github.com/DylanVann). Every image in your list is a `new Image()` instance. The faster it reaches the `loaded` hook, the faster your Javascript thread will be free again.

#### Use getItemLayout

You can set the `getItemLayout` to your `FlatList` component. If all your list item components have the same height (or width, for a horizontal list), passing this prop removes the need for your `FlatList` to dynamically calculate it every time. This is a very desirable optimization technique and if your components have dynamic size, and you really need performance, consider asking your design team if they may think of a redesign in order to perform better.
Your method should look like this, for items with height of, say, `70`:

```js
   getItemLayout = (data, index) => ({
     length: 70,
     offset: 70 * index,
     index
   })
```

#### Use keyExtractor

You can set the `keyExtractor` to your `FlatList` component. This prop is used for caching and as the React `key` to track item re-ordering. For example, if you're using your item id as the key:

```js
   keyExtractor={item => item.id}
```

---